# Grouping collection by year and month in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection, that I would like to achieve group by the year and month.

```
2014
    jan
       2nd
       5th
       ...
    feb
       11th
       12th
       ...
    mar
    ...
2013
    jan
    feb
    mar
    ...
2012
    jan
    feb
    mar
    ...
```

this is my current collection but only by year. I couldn't get what I really wanted with this.

```
$collection =$model->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->date->format('Y');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a Group By on DB::raw('MONTH(*your date variable*)')

For example, try this:

```
$model->orderBy('date')->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(date)'))->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M %Y") as Month)->get();
```